# Kafka producers push events into partition in wrong order

Tags: apache-kafka

What is the recommend way to avoid 'race condition' while pushing multiple events with the same key into topic.

**Producer logs:**

```
13:15:25.503    
sending record: ad4709f78d71d887297f7b82552a7963, step: INSERT, topic: reporting-topic, kafka key: x-11111111

13:15:25.621    
sending record: ad4709f78d71d887297f7b82552a7963, step: UPDATE, topic: reporting-topic, kafka key: x-11111111
```

**Consumer logs:**

```
13:15:25.646
record: ad4709f78d71d887297f7b82552a7963 was not found, step: UPDATE

13:15:25.790    
record: ad4709f78d71d887297f7b82552a7963 was not found after 5 retries, step: UPDATE

13:15:25.794
record: ad4709f78d71d887297f7b82552a7963, step: INSERT
```

I've noticed Kafka records order broken inside partition in some cases:(UPDATE record event before INSERT record event)

Please advice how to 'fix' partition offset issue: do I need to set **linger.ms** producer config or there is more elegant way?

Producer config:

```
  @Bean
  public Map<String, Object> producerProperties() {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

    map.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    acks.ifPresent(acksConfig -> map.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, acksConfig));

    map.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    map.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArraySerializer.class);

    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
  }
```

Comment: Needs more details. How many partitions does your topic have? Order is only guaranteed within one partition

Comment: 20 partitions, since we use each time same key: 'x-11111111' - data will be populated into same partition

Comment: I can't figure out why order is not guaranteed within one partition

Comment: Can you confirm you are only using one producer instance to produce all your data ?

Comment: Nope, multiple producer instances

Comment: Can you share your producer settings?

Comment: Producer settings attached now.